# Visual Studio 2010 Watch - Wrong values

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, watch

I have the following code snippet

```
fscanf( fSettings, "%s", szLine );  
bool x = separateBool   ( szLine );
gSettings.useBE = x;
```

`szLine` contains `useBE=1`. `x` is set to `true` and the VS2010 Pro watch sees it. However, after  value is assigned to `gSettings.useBE` in the last line, the value of `gSettings.useBE` is still visible as false! I have no idea how this is happenning. VS2010 SP1 installed. Many thanks for any input.

[image: Watch VS 2010]

Edit:
The separateBool is the following function:

```
  inline 
  bool separateBool( const char * szStr )   
  {
       std::vector<std::string> res = split(szStr, '=');
       if ( res.size() < 2 )
          ;  /* error */
       return (str2int( res[1] ) == 1 );        
  };
```

The toy version of the "algorithm"

```
bool a = false;
bool b = false;
b = separateBool    ( szLine );
a = b;
a = separateBool    ( szLine );
```

does everything right.

Comment: Please only one statement per line else it's almost impossible to know which statement exactly the debugger is executing. Is `useBE` just a member variable?

Comment: Yes, useBE is a `bool` member of gSettings. As for evaluation, the yellow arrow is to show that the value of `gSettings.useBE` has already been "set".

Comment: So the toy version of this program looks like this: `int main() { const char* szLine ="useBE=1";
bool x = separateBool( szLine );
bool b = x; bool b = separateBool( szLine )` except you are missing what `separateBool` does.  Please detail what that function does, and confirm if the above code still generates your bug.

Comment: What is the signature of `separateBool`? Is `gSettings.useBE` a bit-field by any chance?

Comment: Yakk: See the edit. The toy version does not generate the bug, separateBool is what you would expect it to be.

Comment: Andrey: useBE is a bool. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `Struct Member Alignment` in `Properties->C/C++->CodeGeneration` to **4 bytes** from the original **8 bytes** makes the trick. But I still have no idea why...

Answer (score 0):

Your program assigns to `gSettings.useBE` twice, so there is no reason for alarm because it is seen with two different values.

Since we don't know what `separateBool` does, we must guess.

If I had to guess, `separateBool` has signature like `bool *(char**)` and these semantics -- read one parameter from the string and update the argument to point to the next parameter.

If my assumption is correct, the consequence would be that the second call either finds a parameter that evaluates to `false` or finds no paramenter or some other condition which causes `separateBool` to return `false`.

Comment: Pedro, that's not the case (see the edit). But thanks anyway.